# Is it possible to define routes on model/DTO in ASP.NET Web API (similar to ServiceStack)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

One of the features of ServiceStack that I really liked the focus on DTOs. You define the routes based on the DTO, and defining services that accept DTOs as opposed to controllers. However, I also want to move to ASP.NET Core. Now that it is open source, I can see a way to make a DTO style approach work (with a different controller resolver). Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: You can probably do that by implementing your own middleware based on the route middleware I guess

Answer (score 2):

It should be fairly straight forward. All you're doing is add routes to the route table based on the attributes on DTOs. Take the following example:

```
[Route("/page/{Id}")]
public class RoutesDemo
{
    ...
}
```

Then using the following code you can get the route values from the DTO. Note that I've hardcoded a DTO as an example, but you'd probably want to scan all types within the assembly for the specific attribute to automatically pick them up.

Then using the following code you can get the route values from the DTO:

```
var type = typeof(RoutesDemo);
var attribute = type.GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttribute<RouteAttribute>();
if (attribute != null)
{
    // /page/{Id}
    var routeInfo = attribute.Template;
}
```

From here you'd want to add this route data to your application's route table, recording the type the route is associated to, so once the route is matched, you can pull the data from the object (this is where recording the type comes in).

ServiceStack have a nice fluent interface to do this (see below) but the concept is exactly the same.

```
Routes
    .Add<Hello>("/hello")
    .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name}");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I was going to go down the custom Controller resolver, and resolve the controller based on the type of the DTO. This approach is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could by loading all of the DTOs when the applications starts and iterate over them  and their attributes using reflection.  You could then modify the route tables.  Doesn't sound like it would be terribly difficult.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first approach I'm going to try.